# Return product if there is no match in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

**Product_Table**

```
ProductID     Name       Date  
1             ABC        2020-02-14  
2             XYZ        2020-03-05
```

**Productbreak_Table**

```
BreakID   Product_id      Begin         End  
34          1             2020-01-01    2020-01-30  
35          1             2020-02-01    2020-02-20  
36          2             2020-01-15    2020-01-31  
37          2             2020-02-15    2020-03-01
```

My goal is to get just the products whose `Date` are not between the `Begin` and `End` dates of the productbreak_table

Result should be:

```
ProductID    Name
2            XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (select 1
                  from productbreak pb 
                  where pb.productid = p.productid and
                        p.date between pb.begin and pb.end
                 );
```

Comment: Should be `between` instead of `not between`  
But it works.